# Conditional cell edit in PrimeFaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I want to allow user to edit cells in data table only if some condition is met.

Initially I have tried `<choose>` to achieve this:

```
<p:dataTable var="item" value="${bean.items}" editable="true" editMode="cell">
    <p:column headerText="column A">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${item.isEditable}">
                <p:cellEditor id="title">
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{item.title}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </p:column>
...
```

but it does not work. Another approach is to use `rendered` attribute:

```
<p:column headerText="column A">
    <p:cellEditor rendered="${item.isEditable}">
         <f:facet name="output">
             <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>
         </f:facet>
         <f:facet name="input">
             <p:inputText value="#{item.title}"/>
         </f:facet>
     </p:cellEditor>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.title}" rendered="#{!item.isEditable}"/>
</p:column>
```

that works fine - user are able to edit only allowed cells.

But even if cell is not editable it still has `ui-cell-editing` class and looks like editable cell for user.

What is a correct way to apply condition to cell editing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To properly learn the lesson of JSTL fail, it failed for the reason explained in the following answer: [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) In a nutshell: `#{item}` isn't available at the moment JSTL runs.

Coming back to the concrete question: that style class is been inserted due to the combination `editMode="cell"` and the *physical presence* of `<p:cellEditor>` component in the `<p:column>`. The PrimeFaces datatable renderer isn't at all considering if the `<p:cellEditor>` is rendered or not. It just outright inserts the `ui-editable-column` style class which in turn triggers the `ui-cell-editing` style via JS/jQuery. You were looking in the right direction for the solution, JSTL which can conditionally physically add/remove JSF components in the JSF component tree, but unfortunately it won't work in this construct.

Your best bet is to post [an issue report](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) to the PrimeFaces guys whereby you ask to not only consider the physical presence of `<p:cellEditor>` component, but also its `isRendered()` outcome. Considering PrimeFaces version 3.5, that would be in [line 796 of `DataTableRenderer` class](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTableRenderer.java?spec=svn8714&r=8714#796) which originally looks like this (newlines introduced for readability):

```
String styleClass = selectionEnabled 
    ? DataTable.SELECTION_COLUMN_CLASS 
    : (column.getCellEditor() != null) 
        ? DataTable.EDITABLE_COLUMN_CLASS 
        : null;
```

And should be modified as follows:

```
String styleClass = selectionEnabled 
    ? DataTable.SELECTION_COLUMN_CLASS 
    : (column.getCellEditor() != null && column.getCellEditor().isRendered()) 
        ? DataTable.EDITABLE_COLUMN_CLASS 
        : null;
```

If you can't wait, in the meanwhile you could homegrow a custom renderer.

```
package com.example;

import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer;

public class MyDataTableRenderer extends DataTableRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void encodeCell(FacesContext context, DataTable table, UIColumn column, String clientId, boolean selected) throws IOException {
        // Copypaste here the original encodeCell() source code and make modifications where necessary.
    }

}
```

Then, to get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <description>Overrides the PrimeFaces table renderer with customized cell renderer.</description>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.DataTableRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MyDataTableRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Comment: thank you @BalusC I will definitely try to use custom renderer and post the result here. Thank you so much for comprehensive answer!

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I am going to work on a pull request to replicate this behavior.

Comment: Pull request submitted if anyone is curious: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/908